# Javascript best practice: Calling a file from different locations in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a javascript file that includes a function.
I have 2 files, that include the javascript file and that included function.
The structure could look this way for example:

```
/var/www/file1.jsp
/var/www/content/file2.jsp
```

both include the file `include.js` with the function doSomething()
The function is calling another file that is located on the server via GET.
For example the file is located in `/var/www/index.jsp`

How would be the best way to call the `index.jsp` out of the function with a relative path (absolute pathes are not possible in this context).
The problem is that `file1.jsp` and `file2.jsp` have a different context from which they include the .js file and so the current path for the function is different in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `index.jsp` is always in the same place, I would parse the absolute url from `window.location.href` and construct my path the `index.jsp` right there in `doSomething()`

EDIT:

A better way would be to let the browser do the url parsing for you . Use `window.location.hostname` and then concatenate with the hard-coded path to `index.jsp` relative to the **root directory** of your domain. Feed that concatenated string to your GEt request and all should be well.

Comment: How would you then split the URL, so that you either get `file1.jsp` or `content/file2.jsp`

Comment: see my edit above. By using the root directory as the base of your relative path (as opposed to the current context), no matter where `doSomething()` is, you can hard code a relative path to `index.jsp` (provided you don't move that file around).